# FE user session not available in developer tools device mode

Tags: typo3, typo3-6.2.x

We have made an extension in typo3 (ver. 6.2).
At a point we make a ajax call, where we want to save some values.
In order to check if the user is logged in we use

```
$GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user->user['userid']
```

The userid for the two testusers are greater than 0. The (edited) php that is called looks like this:

```
<?php
$var = $GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user->user['userid'];
if($var > 0) {
    echo "var = ".$var."\n";
    echo "var > 0 - logged in!";
}else{
    echo "var = ".$var."\n";
    echo "var < 1 - not logged in.";
}
?>
```

Our problem is that when we look at the page-source, we can see the content from the if-condition:

```
var = 1 (or: var = 2)
var > 0 - logged in!
```

When we look at the console (F12), we can see the content from the else-condition:

```
var = 
var < 1 - not logged in.
```

The variable is empty here?
The Apache error.log gives a notice:

```
 Trying to get property of non-object in .....
```

Can anyone explain what is going on? If it is a non-object, how come the variable is set to 1 (or 2)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Frontend User Session in TYPO3 is (unless configured differently in the Install Tool) bound to the User-Agent. The browser console uses a different user agent if you set it to another kind of device (e.g. iPhone):

[image: Chrome Developer Tools User agent]

So the user session doesn't apply anymore.

For development purposes or if you're aware of the risks (session hi-jacking), you might change this in the install tool:

[image: Install Tool lockHashKeyWords]

Answer (score 0):

**A)** If you used the code just as you showed within *raw* PHP file it won't work as the `$GLOBALS['TSFE']` object is **NOT** initialized - you didn't specify how do you handle AJAX request, but `Trying to get property of non-object in ...` shows that clearly. If you'll rise log level for development you'd see a notice
`Notice: Undefined index: TSFE in /your/path/to/script.php`

You should create a front-end plugin instead and handle it via custom **typeNum** (preferred) or use **eID mechanismus**. The **eID** *may be* faster in some cases (better performance), but you will have more work with it as you need to initialize TSFE parts still.

**B)** If user is not logged the var `$GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user->user` is `false` otherwise it's an `Array`, you don't need to check the user ID.

**C)** If you want to check integer value and you are not sure if index exists you should use
`intval($GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user->user['uid'])` instead

**D)** TSFE has a property which determines if FE user is logged in or not:

```
if ($GLOBALS['TSFE']->loginUser) {
    echo "User IS logged";
} else {
    echo "User is NOT logged";
}
```

Comment: function functionName(sd) { var dat = JSON.stringify(sd); $.ajax({ url: "path/to/php" type: "GET", data: {dat:dat},

I tried D), and it said "User IS logged" in page-source, and "User is NOT logged" in console...

Comment: @DavidLamhauge you must give more details about what you did, also click in the **Network** panel on the Ajax request and show me what does it return. From my point of view your request is not performed properly, and that JS shows some logged state is just a mistake

Comment: The php-file that is called, is made to save the data I want to save, and it started as a raw PHP file. The $GLOBALS['TSFE'] returned NULL, but after I included the php-file in my main controller.php file, $GLOBALS['TSFE'] has returned the right 'uid'. My concern now is mainly that it that it echoes different values in the sourcecode and the browser console. If it is because they use different user agents, then there is no reason to worry... - or?

Comment: This is a GET request, so copy its path and just paste into address bar of your browser, you'll see the response body, check if it's the expected one

Comment: And if you want to work as expected as I said in point A - you __need__ to make it properly with TYPO3 FE plugin or eID

Comment: @biesoir and lorenz. I have tested it thoroughly and the setup works. The strange behavior comes from the two different user agents. The browsers user agent cannot access '$GLOBALS['TSFE']', and that results in a PHP notice in Apaches error.log. If I copy the path from the GET request into another browser, I am redirected to the login page. Thank both of you for your help!